# 'used' vs 'can be used'

Tags: subjects

> it can be used not only at the task, process of an organization but also **used** to achieve better vertical and/or horizontal integration among the all different levels.

VS

> it can be used not only at the task, process of an organization but also **can be used** to achieve better vertical and/or horizontal integration among the all different levels.

which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one, either

> it can be used not only at the task, process of an organization but also to achieve better vertical and/or horizontal integration among the all different levels.

Or

> it can be used not only at the task, process of an organization but can also be used to achieve better vertical and/or horizontal integration among the all different levels.

"Can be used" needs to go together as a verb phrase, the second time should have all of it or none (can be implied by saying "also").

Some other things for you, if this is your writing.

I don't know what this means:

> at the task, process

And a correction for the last few words:

> among all the different levels.

Comment: Thx Erin, it was taken from the article and I will change it..!